# Mock a class have load native lib

Tags: java, mocking, java-native-interface, jmockit

I have a class with native method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static native boolean NativeMethod();
    static
    {
       System.loadLibrary("mynativelib");
    }
}
```

I am writing unit test for my project and some test case have call this native method. Currently I use **jmockit** to mock MyClass.

mynativelib is build to run on big endian machine, but those unit test is run on my linux PC which is little endian machine, so i got the fowllowing error when run those unit test:

> wrong ELF class : ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause : endianness mismatch)

So my question is :

- Is there a way to mock MyClass but not load mynativelib or can I mock only the native method, not mock the whole class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the whole class while stubbing out the static initializer, by declaring a `@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization = true) MyClass mock` field or parameter.

This will only work, however, if the class has not been initialized during the test run, before it gets to the test with the `@Mocked` declaration.

Comment: Mocking of native methods not supported under JDK 1.5; please filter out method "NativeMethod", or run under JDK 1.6+ ? What is filter out mean here?

Comment: The `@Mocked` annotation has an optional attribute which takes an array of method/constructor signatures to be mocked; "filter out" here means to select only the methods that need to be mocked from the mocked class, leaving out the native methods.